# Understanding Dart's element events

Tags: javascript, dart, mouseevent, frontend

I've started learning Dart and find one thing to be very confusing, namely events that are fired on an Element.

Say I have items in my template, which I wish to delete.

```js
querySelector('.delete').onClick.listen((MouseEvent e) {
        item_id = /* how do I get this value? */
});
```

```html
<button class="delete" data-item="1">Delete</button>
<button class="delete" data-item="2">Delete</button>
...
<button class="delete" data-item="n">Delete</button>
```

How do I access said Element? How do I get its attributes? How do I find out which button was clicked, what value `data-item` had?

I've searched the docs, unfortunately I haven't been able to find anything that has led me in the right direction. I've encountered a method to get a Node object, but since an Element inherits from a Node, I can't really access that either.

Also, any books or great online sources to learn dart for front-end purposes are very much appreciated, as I've also found nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/library-tour#darthtml---browser-based-apps

In the section Handling Events, states : "Events can propagate up and down through the DOM tree. To discover which element originally fired the event, use e.target"

Comment: Thank you! When I compile with dart2js it gives me an error, but it works nonetheless! I'm sorry that I have not found that page before, the Dart documentation and introductions on dartlang.org are a bit messy and unorganized :(. I know Dart is an optionally typed language, but why does the following

`import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js';

void main() {
  querySelectorAll(".delete").onClick.listen((MouseEvent event) {
    print(event.target.getAttribute('data-item'));
  });
}` give 

`The method 'getAttribute' is not defined for the class 'EventTarget'.`?

Comment: Agree, not allways easy to navigate in the Dart doc, but have lately given better structure. Tested and you are right. Tried with a little cast and now the Element is accessible.     `Element eItem = e.target;
    print('Element ' + eItem.id.toString());`

Comment: It is indeed. Thank you very much! I think this topic is closed.

Comment: Great. A small tip, inspection of the object in the debugger, could give info on the type, I use this a lot to get a grip on the dom structures, they a quite complex. Hence the idea with the cast.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `querySelectorAll()` you get an `ElementList` and can listen to click events of all `delete` elements at once.

```
querySelectorAll('.delete').onClick.listen((MouseEvent e) {
  print((e.target as HtmlElement).dataset['item']);
});
```

With `e.target` you get a reference to the clicked element. For autocompletion we cast to `HtmlElement` and by using it's `dataset` property we can access its `data-...` properties.

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/e5058860939b34bbbf9de82432356180)

The console view shows the `data-item` value of each clicked element.

Comment: Thank you. That is a really helpfull snippet!

Comment: Glad to hear you find it helpful.